# Capped Probability and Expected Payoff

Tags: probability, expectation

You keep flipping a coin until you get a head. You are paid 2^(# of flips) dollars. Suppose that if you make more than 210 dollars, you will only receive 210 dollars. What is the expected payoff of this game?

I am very confused how to approach this question. Is the expected payoff only half of 210=105 because the probability of getting a head is 1/2?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You throw $T^nH$ the payout is $Min(2^n, 210)$ and the probability is $\frac {1}{2^{n+1}}$.  Now just a matter of writing out the infinite sum (summands are constant for a while, then geometric).

Answer (score 1):

Play the game $256$ times. The payoff table is:

$$\begin{array} {c|c}
result&\#&payoff\\
\hline
H&128&256\\
TH&64&256\\
T^2H&32&256\\
T^3H&16&256\\
T^4H&8&256\\
T^5H&4&256\\
T^6H&2&256\\
T^{7+}H&2&420
\end{array}
$$

Expected payoff per game is (total payoff)/256 $\approx 8.64$

Comment: I am a little confused how did you come up with payoff 256?

Comment: if you throw H you get \$2, you do this 128 times on average, so 256. if you throw TH you get \$4, you do this 64 time on average, so 256. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of $105$ is not right. Let us look at the money you make.

With probability $1/2$, you get a head immediately, payoff $2$.

With probability $1/4$, you get tail then head, payoff $4$.

With probability $1/8$, you get two tails then head, payoff $8$.

Continue $\dots$.

With probability $1/128$, you get 6 tails then head, payoff $128$.

With probability $1/128$, you get $7$ or more tails, payoff $210$.

Now you can compute the expectation.

Comment: you can stop playing the game after 7 throws

Comment: @JonMarkPerry:  Effectively you can, after $7$ tails the house might as well fork over the cash. But the problem said you toss until you get a head.

Comment: nice, i wonder what other games this house has...

Comment: @AndréNicolas with probability of 1/128 you still get payoff 210?

Comment: With one probability $1/128$, you get $128$ (if you get first head on the $7$-th trial. With another $1/128$ you get $210$.  One could combine these, but for the sake of clarity I chose not to.

Comment: So the expectation would be 2*1/2+1/4*4+1/8*8+...+1/128*128+1/128*210?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Fairly close to $9$ bucks,